# ¿Cómo mejorar la edición de una lista de elementos en linq c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, revisión-de-código

Lo que busco es mejorar o saber si hay una forma distinta de realizar la edicion de los elementos de una lista para luego ser almacenada en la base de datos, actualmente estoy utilizando LINQ en C#, aqui les dejo el codigo esperando de su ayuda.

```
public bool DestroyItems(int userID, long projectID, int disciplineID) 
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new buildbinderEntities())
        {
            // obtengo la lista
            var updateElements = db.ContractItems.Where(w => w.ProjectID == projectID && w.DisciplineID == disciplineID).ToList();
            // recorro la lista para modificar cada elemento por separado
            foreach (var update in updateElements)
            {
                update.DeletedFlag = true;
                update.DeletedDate = DateTime.Now;
                update.DeletedUser = userID;

                db.ContractItems.Attach(update);
                db.Entry(update).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la librería [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) en Nuget [EntityFramework.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/) para crear un [batch update](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended#batch-update-and-delete).

```
using (var db = new buildbinderEntities())
{
    db.ContractItems
        .Where(w => w.ProjectID == projectID && w.DisciplineID == disciplineID)
        .Update(t => new ContractItem
        {
            DeletedFlag = true,
            DeletedDate = DateTime.Now,
            DeletedUser = userID
        });
}
```

De esta forma estás evitando realizar N+1 llamadas a la base de datos para hacer la actualización sino que al ejecutarse se crea un `UPDATE` con un `WHERE` directamente sin necesidad de pasar por el `SELECT` ni hacer `foreach`

Comment: Muy interesante esta librería, no la conocía. La pega que le veo es tener que depender de una librería externa que se podría quedar desactualizada y que contiene más cosas que quizás no se necesiten. Además la implementación de los procesos batch dependen de la base de datos y que solo está implemenmtado para SQL Server y mySQL. De todas formas lo guardo en mi colección de enlaces.

Answer (score 2):

Si la operacion la realizas dentro del contexto de EF la entidad aun se esta trackeando por lo que no necesitas el `Attach` o  del `Entry(update).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Puedes realizarlo directo

```
    using (var db = new buildbinderEntities())
    {
        // obtengo la lista
        var updateElements = db.ContractItems.Where(w => w.ProjectID == projectID && w.DisciplineID == disciplineID);

        foreach (var update in updateElements)
        {
            update.DeletedFlag = true;
            update.DeletedDate = DateTime.Now;
            update.DeletedUser = userID; 
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Ademas puedes realizas el `SaveChanges()` al final cuando hayas actualizado todas las entidades

Comment: Gracias, por tu respuesta. ¿sabes si hay otra forma de editar los elementos sin  hacer uso del foreach ?

Comment: Lo que veo es que trabajas los datos de una seleccion previa. Distinto seria si quieres mantener estas propiedades como log entonces podrias implementar una interface que implemente la entidad ContactItem entonces cuando eliminas la entidad validas si implementa la interfaz y asignas los valores, pero seria una operacion que se realiza junto al item y no en una operacion posterior. Esto que comento se aplcia cuando creas los tipicos campos de fecha u usuario de creacion y modificacion de la entidad